# The VLG component does not expand regardless of the length of the child

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, layout

This is my hierarchy in the Unity scene:

- Vertical Layout Group

  - ScrollView (Horizontal)

    - Text (Very long)

I set the graphics to work perfectly in portrait mode with mobile device screens. But when I use the graphics on a tablet, or when I rotate the device, I have to enlarge the elements, and here the problem arises.

I can't find the correct way to expand the elements, I want many ScrollViews in the Vertical Layout Group, and I want to be able to scroll horizontally to view the texts inside, that's what I'm asking.

The question is convoluted and complex to explain, I explain it in three different ways (talking about the same thing, so they may seem similar), you choose which one is more understandable to you:

---

Explanation 1

The Vertical Layout Group expands autonomously, covering a large part of the screen.

The problem arises when I have to decide how to enlarge the ScrollView, I cannot use the anchors because they are replaced by the Vertical Layout Group, and I cannot use the "Control Child Size" and "Child Force Expand" option, because it would expand beyond the Vertical Layout Group, if the text component inside was longer, thus making the Scroll useless.

I want the ScrollView to expand only within the limits of the Vertical Layout Group, and therefore not be affected by the length of the internal text component (so that I can scroll it) (PS. I cannot use a Layout Element, because the text can vary both horizontally and vertically, and because the ScrollView is equipped with another Vertical Layout Group (I need it to manage the vertical development of the text, if it want to expand in height))

---

Explanation 2

I would like the ScrollView to expand horizontally until it touches the limits of the Vertical Layout Group.
This I would be able to do by enabling "Control Child Size" and "Child Force Expand".

However, I would like one more thing, which is that the ScrollView does not expand beyond the limits of the Vertical Layout Group. This problem is caused when the Text component (of variable size) will be longer than the length of the Vertical Layout Group.

I would therefore like the ScrollView to expand into the Vertical Layout Group, without being influenced by the size of the child.

---

Explanation 3

Trying to seem clearer, to enlarge the ScrollView to the limits of the VLG, I have to enable both "Control Child Size" and "Child Force Expand" (I can't use anchors, because it's the same VLG that replaces them with its own), but putting "Control Child Size", if the child Text were to be longer than the VLG, it would make the ScrollView enlarge (and I don't want this to happen! otherwise the ScrollView, if it were as long as its component, would make no sense! I want that the ScrollView stretch to the limits of the VLG, but don't exceed them!)

[image: 1]

Comment: you need to explain in more detail what have you tried that failed for a better understanding of what you want and where are you stuck at. Check if [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDBVRcHhc0M) might be of help

Comment: I added a part, even if it seems repetitive to me, I hope it helps

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically scale scroll view to the size of the vertical layout group? I'm a little confused what you want for the text group. What should scale to what exactly? In your example photo do you just want the scroll to expand to the container but still be a scroll?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it even clearer. I want the ScrollView to expand to the limits of the VLG, that's all. The problem, however, is that having a very long internal text, if I enable the options on the VLG, the ScrollView expands to the length of the text, making it useless because it is impossible to scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling "Control Child Size" and "Child Force Expand" in the VLG made the ScrollView dependent on the length of the child. However, by also enabling "Control Child Size" in an additional VLG in the ScrollView, the problem vanished. In practice, the ScrollView stops depending on the child, so it is it who controls, instead of being controlled.

Answer (score 0):

After the clarification, I believe I understand what you'd like to achieve. If this is not what you'd like, please correct my implementation so I can answer the question properly.

Here is the hierarchy I have set up.
[image: Example]

Here is the UI working with the current setup.

[image: Example 2]

As the UI is rather extensive, if you make any changes at runtime, you will need to make calls to rebuild the layout if you happen to change the text's length. The scroll will not change properly in a single update cycle. To update it at runtime, you can make a call to [`LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildImmediate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate.html) while passing in a proper `RectTransform` for rebuilding.

Comment: Your answer was not correct for my case (this does not mean it cannot be correct for others, we are talking about an intricate graphics problem, it is normal that my project may be different), but it helped me to understand the solution. Therefore I give you the bounty (Thanks for the help!), But the answer I have to publish it with what I have done to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

I may have misunderstood the question, but is this solved by just changing the anchor points of the ScrollView to fit the Vertical Layout Group (no "Control Child Size" and "Child Force Expand" needed):

Using Anchor points to stretch to fit the parent object:

[image: 1]

Comment: The Vertical Layout Group automatically checks and arranges the anchors of the children, with the "Child Alignment" option

Comment: @FreeLearning to be clearer, can you turn off all the ticks on the Vertical Layout Group:
Child control size (off), Use Child Scale (off), Child force Expand (off). The text expansion maybe to do with its settings so you may need to look at the horizontal overflow of the Text component

An image of what you want would help!

Comment: You cannot manually edit the anchors of child objects of a VLG, except by the setting in the VLG. PS. I added an image.